# What form of Formality does Kikuji originally use when talking about Chikako Kurimoto in chapter two?

Tags: translation, japanese-language, yasunari-kawabata, thousand-cranes

I am reading [Thousand Cranes (千羽鶴, Senbazuru) by Yasunari Kawabata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thousand_Cranes) at the moment after finding the slim booklet in my late grandfather's library.

In chapter two, in english titled *The Grove in the Evening Sun*, in German *Die Abendsonne über dem Wald*, I came to the sub-part number two. Suddenly, I noticed that the protagonist, Kikuji, was explicitly talking about Chikako Kurimoto - at least in the translation into German by Sachiko Yatsushiro - not using a form like "Fräulein Kurimoto" (Misses Kurimoto) like Yukiko Inamura he was talking to but instead using the somewhat rough "die Kurimoto" (the Kurimoto). The most noticeable section, after this has happened 3 times, explicitly calls this out for the fourth time:

> Und was mochte sie von ihm denken, daß er ihre Lehrerin einfach "die Kurimoto" nannte?<sup>1</sup>

My best translation into English would be this:

> And what might she think of him that he called her teacher simply "the Kurimoto"?

This implies, that in the Japanese original, there was a very specific form of formality that was different from the normal, possibly expected form of "Kurimoto-San" or "Kurimoto-sama".

To a European reader, it might not be noticeable at the first mention - and indeed it slipped my mind till that sentence above. However, it should be quite more noticeable for a reader of the Japanese original, as honorifics and formal language (Keigo) are often lost in the translations. In this case, Sachiko Ytshushiro did a tremendous job of using the closest formal addresses when possible, yet it still is impossible to see which form of formality - or rather *informality* Kikuji used to refer to Chikako Kurimoto.

So, how does Kikuji refer to her?

---

1 - Yasunari Kawabata, Sachiko Yatsushiro (transl.): Tausend Kraniche, Fischer Verlag Frankfurt am Main & Hamburg (1956), p.54.